# Range picker Google Sheet Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, add-on

I'm trying to retrieve the selection of a data range of the type A1:B2 from a sidebar of a sheet.
I tried to do it on an onBlur method of input, the problem is that when I click on the cell the getActiveRange just returns the clicked cell (e.g. A1) and the function doesn't wait for me to finish my cell selection to return the full getActiveRange (e.g. A1:B2).

Stéphane

Comment: Hi ! Please share your Apps Script code along with a sample Spreadsheet (with no sensitive data) so that we can find out what you are trying to achieve and what is your problem. Thanks !

Comment: Thank's , Here is the link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zXj6LtXFdc1hYj_A_Yj581Egz-x2-QlvNILGbM1LtjE/copy

Comment: Hi ! Please grant access to your Spreadsheet as it is currently private.